# Printing Chinese characters to a Line Printer using the WritePrinter API

Tags: c++, winapi, character

I'm trying to print asian language characters to a line printer(EPSON LQ-2090) using the writePrinter method in c++.

ANSI characters print fine, but when I throw asian language characters at it, they come out like garbage.

Note that if I change the DocInfo datatype parameter to "TEXT" instead of "RAW" then also the asian language characters do not print.

Is there a way to get asian language or Unicode characters to print correctly?

Comment: standard C++ has no function writePrinter so you might want to tell/tag the library/API you are using

Comment: I guess u are using windows API writePrinter

Comment: yes it is windows API.

Comment: How do you print? Which is the source-encoding? What is the expected Encoding? HOW do you transform between These Encodings?

Comment: I just give string of wchar_t to the writePrinter method.if you see the signature of writePrinter method BOOL WritePrinter( _In_ HANDLE hPrinter, _In_ LPVOID pBuf, _In_ DWORD cbBuf, _Out_ LPDWORD pcWritten ); it takes buffer of type LPVOID as data for printing.it dosen't matter what is the type of buffer char * or wchar_t *.

Comment: BTW i used MultiByteToWideChar with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: The question is: WHAT is your printed expecting??? As far as I see, your Printer is not able to print asian characters by itself! So you Need to use the normal "GDI" function to create a page and do the printing with "DrawText"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use WritePrinter(), you bypass the printer driver and write the printing commands directly to the printer.  That does typically make output on these kind of dot-matrix printers a *lot* faster.  But you'll miss out on the support built into Windows to render arbitrary fonts.  You'll use the fonts built into the printer's firmware instead.  Which are usually very modest, supporting only Western glyphs with just a few styles.  And requiring special escape commands to activate.

You'll need the programming manual for the printer to find out how to switch fonts.  If the firmware doesn't support the glyphs you need then you're back to putting the printer into graphics instead of text mode.  Making it just as slow as the printer driver does with the added headache of generating the graphics drawing commands.

Comment: thank you Hans Passant it help me a lot.i need to print 60 lines in 90 seconds. its kind of requirement,I think it is not possible if i use graphics mode instead of text mode. Is there any way to change the font so that i can print asian Language characters?

Comment: can you please tell me. Is there any Alternative to writePrinter API? which will not bypass the printer driver. and i dont want to use DrawTextEx API.

Comment: No, there is no alternative.  I would of course have mentioned it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Print asian language characters like garbage is an encoding problem, I`m using EPSON LQ-1600KIIIH, which support gbk raw buffer, as you mentioned WritePrinter takes LPVOID buffer, what you need to do is encoding the buffer correctly, for example, using qt QTextCodec encoding the UTF-16 stream into gbk buffer, and then WritePrinter:

```
// Message to print contains chinese "中文" 
QString msg("\u4e2d\u6587")

// Encoding, from UTF-16 to GBK (my locale encoding)
QByteArray bmsg = QTextCodec::codecForLocale()->fromUnicode(msg);

// Write operation
WritePrinter( m_PrinterHandle,bmsg.data(), bmsg.size(), &dwBytesWritte );
```

bmsg.data() return gbk encoding char* buffer '\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4'.

you need to find out which encoding EPSON LQ-2090 support，printer sold by different regions and countries may have different built-in encode, hope useful to you.

My experience is that WritePrinter did not bypassing the printer driver, because if you install the wrong driver, printer act unexpected.